# What is the difference between lscgid: execve():<filename>Permission denied and Error 500 Internal Server Error?

Tags: apache, http

Normally when I upload a CGI program but forget to give it the execute permissions I get an `Internal Server Error 500` back when it is accessed. But now I have suddenly got - `lscgid: execve():<filename>Permission denied`.

What is the difference between these?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I've edited your question to improve its clarity and make it easier to read. Hopefully that will help improve your chances of receiving an answer. Good luck.